# Keras showing multiple processes for one training

Tags: tensorflow, caching, memory, keras

Whenever I launch a training with Keras, I end up with multiples processes (dozens), as you can see on this [htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZRjT.png). Is that normal?

Could it be the reason of why I experienced memory issues ? The cache becomes full as the training goes, then the swap is activated, and after some hours the machine needs to be restarted.

The training is done on a single GPU, using fit_generator:

```
training_model.fit_generator(
    generator=train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=config["steps"],
    epochs=config["epochs"],
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

- Keras 2.2.4
- tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1
- CUDA 10.0

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post your fit_generator code ? Are you using multiprocessing ?

Comment: I edited my post! I am not using multiprocessing or a defined numbers of workers. Everything is by default.

Answer (score 0):

From the information which you have provided, it seems to be the case of Out of Memory.

Please confirm if you are using GPU. You can check it by running the command,

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Also, if we use GPU, the processes can be monitored in `nvtop` and not on `htop`.

The best way to identify which operation in your entire project is consuming more memory and time is to use **`Tensorflow Profiler`**.

So, you can think of upgrading your Tensorflow Version to 1.15 or 2.2 if possible in which `model.fit` does the job of `model.fit_generator` too.

Code to use `Profiler` is shown below:

```
# Create a TensorBoard callback
logs = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

tboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logs,
                                                 histogram_freq = 1,
                                                 profile_batch = '500,520')

model.fit(ds_train,
          epochs=2,
          validation_data=ds_test,
          callbacks = [tboard_callback])
```

High level details of the execution can be viewed in the Overview page of `Profiler` can be viewed in the `Profile` tab of `Tensorboard` as shown below.

[image]

From the above screenshot, it can be understood that Input Processing is taking most of the Execution Time (83%).

Also, it will provide us the Recommendations to reduce the Memory Consumption and hence to `Optimize` our Execution.

Also, other Options in the `Tools` dropdown like `TraceViewer` provide useful information like execution information at Operations Level.

For more information, please refer [Profiler Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras), [Profiler Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) and [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXHAQIhhMhI).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I confirm that I'm using a GPU. I would love to use the Profiler, but the migration to TF 2.2 will be complicated for now. I don't think my issue is caused by out of memory, the memory "used" is about 6GB out of 128GB. The cache/buff is taking all the remaining memory. Thanks for the nvtop tip, it's really helpful.